# jQuery Tokeninput event on No results

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jQuery Tokeninput as a way to add authors on a book creating page.

If the entered author exists in the database it will show in a dropdown as a clickable token. If, however, there are no results found, the dropdown will show only a message informing the user their query yeilded no results. What I would like is for Tokeninput to provide a clickable option in the dropdown on No results, instead of just showing a message.

Because my Tokeninput field serves only to find existing authors. If a user enters a name that does not yet exist, I would like to offer an option to create him/her now. So, instead of just having a message saying "No results found", I would like to have a clickable option along the lines of "Entered author does not yet exist. Add 'name surname' now?" which then shows a non-Tokeninput form for adding a new author.

Tokeninput source code: 
https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at enabling Free Tagging, and making use of the `onFreeTaggingAdd` callback, so that you can use the search query the user has already typed into the TokenInput, and save them typing it in twice.

This additionally has the plusside of allowing a user to create a new author that may be a substring of an existing author. (e.g. Chris Smith, Chris Smithson)

Something a little bit like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("/url/to/your/script/", {
        allowFreeTagging: true,
        noResultsText: "Author not recognised, hit enter to add",
        onFreeTaggingAdd: addNewAuthor(hiddenInput, token)
    });
});

function addNewAuthor(hiddenInput, token) {
    //Insert form-launching code here, using the author name in the token parameter
}
```

N.B. Ensure you are using the latest version of the plug-in from Github for freetagging functionality, the version on loopj.com is outdated.